# Accessing Json in PHP

Tags: php, json

```
//Decoded Json data
object(stdClass)[250]
  public '2013-02-05' =>
    object(stdClass)[114]
      public 'bounce_count' => int 1
      public 'avg_time_on_site' => int 237
  public '2013-02-06' =>
    object(stdClass)[115]
      public 'bounce_count' => int 6
      public 'avg_time_on_site' => int 983
$json_data=json_decode($result);
//$result has the json string
```

How to retrieve the bounce_count, avg_time_on_site for a particular date along with the date where the date will be changing in php.

Answer (score 2):

```
$json_data=json_decode($result, true);

foreach($json_data as $date=>$val){

   echo "Date : ".$date;
   echo "bounce_count : ".$val['bounce_count'];
   echo "avg_time_on_site : ".$val['avg_time_on_site'];
   echo "===========================<br>";
}
```

Comment: `$json_data=json_decode($result, true);` Please note the second argument here 'true' which will give your o/p as array insted of object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply, it worked. Thanks for the help.